# GNOME shell crash

Tags: gnome, 18.04, gnome-shell, xps

Sometimes (roughly once a week), GNOME shell closes down, and I get to the view as seen in the [attached photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pItIe.jpg) (sorry for bad quality but think it should be enough). After that nothing happens and I have to restart the machine.

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 on a Dell XPS 13 9370.

Any ideas why?

**Update:**

It seems to be some problem related to the Graphics card (maybe not a shocker):

```
[drm] GPU HANG: ecode 9:0:0xdfb7ffc3, in gnome-shell [1958], reason: Hang on rcs0, action: reset

i915 0000:00:02.0: Resetting rcs0 after gpu hang

[drm:gen8_reset_engines [i915]] *ERROR* rcs0: reset request timeout
```

Comment: To me this will be a hardware issue. Follow up on kernel messages with the command "dmesg -w". There should not be too many red messages. When I got my xps 13 3950 it would freeze every 15 - 20 minute. Turned out they have replaced the mother board. Problem here is that the issue does not occur frequently, however. Will be difficult to track.

Comment: @vanadium Thanks, will try next time it happens